# Get the last update time for Google Finance for currency

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am using google sheets and getting currency with this code:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDTRY")
```

it looks perfect and working but result sometimes return me old value of currency. to be sure, I want to get last update date and hour for given currency. Also I have try "tradetime" but not working:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDTRY";"tradetime")
```